# Does mobile application also had sessionStorage like web browser

Tags: web-storage

Respected
I am currently working with an web and mobile application and I have a doubt that does mobile application also had sessionStorage or not

is sessionStorage is available or not in mobile applications or not. If there when will the sessionStorage wil be cleared and how to access it

N B : I am creating an mobile application which can be available in Google Playstore and it doesn't have any relation with mobile web-browser

Comment: It all depends on which technologies are you working with. Quickly speaking, sessionStorage is a web-only concept that has no relation to native programs, but of course you can make normal programs with web-like technologies that simulate/bundle a browser.